# Which Golden Thread Matrilineal "Clan" maps to my mtDNA haplogroup?

Tags: mitochondrial-dna

I understand the 'seven daughters of Eve' is now up to 36 clans per a 'golden thread' figure in a recent issue (Fall 2016) of American Ancestors. Do the names map to haplogroups? My mtDNA haplogroup is V15A - which daughter's name goes with my haplogroup? Is there a table mapping clan names to haplogroups?

[image: daughters of Eve]

In the figure, the colors of the threads correspond to continents - gold for Europe, red for Africa, green is Asia, purple is the Americas. The rings correspond to 10,000 years increments.

Comment: It's a great marketing gimmick, but what's the likelihood that an early "Limber" actually named her child *Limber*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ISOGG Wiki has [a table mapping clan names to haplogroups](http://isogg.org/wiki/Oxford_Ancestors_haplogroup_nicknames).

Of the 36 clans in your diagram, all but 4 of them are listed: Hera, Irena, Rhea and Wanda.

The table also gives associations for 6 names that are not among the clans in your diagram:  Iris, Lila, Latifa, Rohani, Ulaana and Wilma.

Your V15a group would be Velda.